# Reading Data from Serial Port RS232 in Visual Basic 2013 (Visual Studio .NET)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

We are trying getting weight from weighing machine.

> While reading in Hyper-terminal in windows XP using COM1 we getting
>   the right values. But reading data in Visual Basic 2013 (in Windows 10
>   Pro) on my laptop using USB to COM port convertor cable we are getting
>   different values like x, ?, 3, &, etc. Kindly suggest the solution so
>   that we can get the right data through code.
>
> Our Code is:

```
 With Me.mvSerialPort
        .PortName = "COM11"          ' as shown in device manager
        .BaudRate = 2400
        .Parity = Parity.None
        .StopBits = StopBits.One
        .DataBits = 8
        .Handshake = Handshake.None
        .DtrEnable = True
        .RtsEnable = True
        .NewLine = vbCrLf
        .ReadTimeout = 1000
        .WriteTimeout = 1000
    End With

'Function Code
    Private Function ReadCOM() As String
        Do
            If Me.mvThread_Stop = True Then Exit Do
            Try
                Try
                    If Me.mvSerialPort.IsOpen Then
                        Me.mvSerialPort.Close()
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    '
                End Try

                Try
                    Me.mvSerialPort.Open()
                    If Me.mvSerialPort.IsOpen Then
                        'Thread.Sleep(200)
                        Thread.Sleep(Val(Me.TextBox4.Text))
                        Dim svMessage As String = ""
                        Try
                            'svMessage = Me.mvSerialPort.ReadLine()
                            svMessage = Me.mvSerialPort.ReadExisting
                            updateStatus(svMessage)
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            'Me.mvThread_Stop = True
                        End Try
                    End If
                    Me.mvSerialPort.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Me.mvSerialPort.Close()
                    '
                End Try
            Catch ex As TimeoutException
                'updateStatus(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        Loop
        Return ""
    End Function

    Public Delegate Sub updateStatusDelegate(ByVal newStatus As String)
    Public Sub updateStatus(ByVal newStatus As String)
        Try
            If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                Dim upbd As New updateStatusDelegate(AddressOf updateStatus)
                Me.Invoke(upbd, New Object() {newStatus})
            Else
                Dim svSplit() As String = Split(newStatus, " ")
                Me.TextBox4.Text = svSplit(svSplit.Count - 1)
                RichTextBox1.Text = newStatus & vbCrLf & RichTextBox1.Text
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            '
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is not VB.NET

Comment: It is very buggy code, you must get rid of all the Open and Close calls.  Thread.Sleep is an ugly hack that will randomly not work the way you hope, be sure to get ReadLine() working by setting the NewLine property correctly.  Garbled data can only easily be explaining by getting the configuration wrong, Baudrate, Parity, DataBits and StopBits settings.